# Reference and labels (beginner)

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, back-referencing

I'm starting to work on Latex and I have a math paper to write and basically I need to creat a reference I think. The text is:

Definition 2. The function f(x)...

According to definition 2 we have etc.

Basically when I click 2 I need to go back to definition 2. I have no idea how to do it. Should I use hyperref or cleveref ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TEX.SE! You can see this post to learn how to use the `hyperref` package: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/hyperlinks. It's all about `\label{#}` what you want to reference (e.g. an equation) and type `\ref{#}` where you want to have that reference.

Answer (score 5):

You would give the definition a `\label` and print the number of the definition with `\ref`.  You can get the page number with `\pageref`.  The `hyperref` package redefines `\ref` to turn the reference into a hyperlink.  This also works for other things, such as sections and figures.  (For equation numbers, however, you would use `\eqref`.)  Here is an example using `amsthm`:

You might need to compile the document a second time for TeX to find every reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{The Natural Numbers}\label{sec:N}

Peano arithmetic takes as axiomatic the number \(0\) and the successor
function \(s\).

\begin{defn}\label{defn:one}
\( 1 \coloneqq s(0) \)
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}\label{defn:two}
\( 2 \coloneqq s(1) \)
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}\label{defn:plus}
\[ n + m =
  \begin{cases}
     n               &\text{if } m = 0 \\
     s(n+m^{\prime}) &\text{if } m = s(m^{\prime})
   \end{cases} 
\]
\end{defn}

\section{What is 1+1?}\label{sec:two}
By definitions \ref{defn:plus} and \ref{defn:one}, \( 1 + 1 = 1 + s(0) =
s(1 + 0) = s(1) \).  Therefore, \( 1+1 = 2 \) by definition \ref{defn:two}.

\end{document}
```

You can tweak this if you want.  For example, you could remove the `[section]` option from `defn` and instead write

```
definition \ref{defn:two}` in section \ref{sec:N}
```

or

```
definition \ref{defn:two} on page \pageref{defn:two}
```

I kept this minimal, but you’ll also almost certainly want to use some of the other options and commands of [the `hyperref` package.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html)

Comment: The OP wants hyperlinks, so you need to add `\usepackage{hyperref}`...

Comment: @Rmano Good catch!

Comment: When `amsmath` and `amsthm` are used together, `amsmath` should be loaded first.  Since `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, that should be `\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks.